# Data retrieval from JAVA DB in eclipse located in jdk1.7.0_06

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I am trying to retrieve data installed on the database server JAVA DB located in jdk1.7.0_06. I am able to make connection to the server and create the database. But i am getting following error for the compilation and running:

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:AddressBook
```

Please can you help me! Thank you

Comment: Did you load the jdbc driver for jdbc (e.g. by calling Class.forName("drivername") before trying to connect)?

Comment: @Heisenbug, I wondered long time back about that issue. Can you please tell me how can i do it. I love to do it!!!!

Comment: @Pyranja, I am practising the exercise mentioned in a book "How to Program" by Deitel and in that exercise there is nothing like that. Meanwhile, i wonder whether JAVA DB in the above JDK contains the driver.

Comment: It contains the driver. Have you set your Eclipse build path to recognize the Java DB jar files?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, I didn't set it. Can you substantiate me how i can do it,Please?

Comment: You would right-click on your project, click Build Path, click Configure Build Path, click Libraries tab, click Add External JARs button, and then load the appropriate jar files from the database lib directory, including derby.jar and possibly derbyrun.jar.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, Yes i did everything as you have said above. Now i am getting following error: Database 'AddressBook' not found where i have that database. Can you please tell me the potential error source.

Comment: I wonder if you need to set the `derby.system.home` property as the Java DB tutorials suggest. Have you tried this? Something like, `System.setProperty("derby.system.home", DERBY_HOME_PATH);` where the second parameter is the path to your database's home directory.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, i think i didn't but i am sure that i have set some envariable variables via command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stated, "I wonder if you need to set the `derby.system.home` property as the Java DB tutorials suggest. Have you tried this? Something like, `System.setProperty("derby.system.home", DERBY_HOME_PATH);` where the second parameter is the path to your database's home directory."

And you replied:

> @HovercraftFullOfEels, i think i didn't but i am sure that i have set some envariable variables via command line.

@Dorji: that doesn't set the System properties in your JVM though. I still think that you need to set this property before using your database.  For example,

```
public class Test {
   public static final String DERBY_HOME = "derby.system.home";

   // ***** the two Strings below will be different for you *****
   public static final String DERBY_HOME_PATH = "D:/DerbyDB";
   private static final String DB_NAME = "sample";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.setProperty(DERBY_HOME, DERBY_HOME_PATH);
      Connection conn = null;
      try {
         Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:" + DB_NAME);

      } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
            | ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
         if (conn == null) {
            System.exit(-1);
         }
      }

      // .... etc...
```

My derby.system.home directory is D/:DerbyDB, and my database resides in the D/:DerbyDB/sample directory:

[image]

This of course will be different for you.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I am gonna try yours now. Thank you!

Comment: I tried and there is still the same error message. I have three classes called Person, PersonQueries and AddressBookDisplay. Can you help me please?

Comment: I am still facing the problem that the database i created is not found. Please is there any one could help me?

Comment: I got the solution for my answer with following URL specifying my database location: jdbc:derby:C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_06\\db\\bin\\AddressBook